# Nodejs subprocess not waiting on finish while logging output

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, subprocess, virtualenv

Well I'm trying to get a nodejs process to launch a python script. - And this python script logs while it is busy - as it logs I wish to display this in the console window used by the nodejs process.

The python script is really trivial

```
from time import sleep
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('small text testing')
    sleep(10)
    raise Exception('test')
```

prints 'small text testing', sleeps for 10 seconds(!) and then raises an exception which is uncaught and thus finishes the script.

In node I tried to get this to work with:

```
  const { exec } = require('child_process');
  const exec_str = '. BackgroundServer/BackgroundServer/bin/activate && python BackgroundServer/main.py 1';

  const child = exec(exec_str,
    {
        // detachment and ignored stdin are the key here:
        detached: true,
        stdio: [ 'ignore', 1, 2 ]
    });
  child.unref();
  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
  child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.error(data.toString());
  });
```

However this "fails" in the sense that it will only print after the python process has finished running.

Now I know it is possible to run a script through `spawn` but that would require me to create a temporary script, give that script permissions and then execute that script. Not optimal either.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing much about javascript or node.js I am pretty sure your problem is due to the fact that Python buffers its output if it is run as subprocess.

To fix this issue, you can do either manually ensure that Python flushes the buffer by adding calls to `sys.stdout.flush()` as

```
import sys
from time import sleep
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('small text testing')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(10)
    raise Exception('test')
```

or you can force Python to not be buffered also when used as a subprocess by calling the intrepreter with the `-u` argument, thus modifying exec_str to

```
const exec_str = '. BackgroundServer/BackgroundServer/bin/activate && \ 
python -u BackgroundServer/main.py 1';
```

The first solution will always flush the output, if that is desirable and you use it in another place, without you having to think about the `-u` option. However, I would still recommend the second approach as it still allows the code to run buffered (which sometimes can be what you want) and also when working with longer scripts you may have to insert quite a number of manual `sys.stdout.flush()` calls otherwise.

Also, as a sidenote, there is no need for raising an exception in the Python script. It will end anyway, when it reaches its last line.

Comment: @paul23 Did this solve your issue, or was it not the buffering that caused the problem?